# Listing all sidebars

Tags: plugins, widgets, sidebar, list

How to list all existing sidebars?

I want to show them all in the drop down list (so each item should have also the right value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only gel list of registered sidebars, from variable **$wp_registered_sidebars**.

```
<?php
global $wp_registered_sidebars;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($wp_registered_sidebars);
echo '</pre>';
```